# ASP.NET Web Forms - Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I hate writing UIs so I choose to use this older tech because I get a built-in graphical UI designer.

Here is what I am trying to do:
`Process.Start("file:///F:/Dashboard%20Files/Open%20Issues.htm");`

And this works when I run the build, seamlessly, but for some reason when I publish it I get this error in event viewer:
`Exception message: The system cannot find the file specified`

I do see this in the event logs message, perhaps someone has a one-liner to get around this:

```
Request URL:       http://investments.com/A00-Home.aspx
Request path:      /A00-Home.aspx
User host address: 10.XXX.XXX.XXX (local 10.* address)
User:
Is authenticated:  False
```

My thoughts are that I need to somehow put integrated authentication into the web.config file. Is this the issue?

Tried this:
`Process.Start("file:///F:/Dashboard%20Files/Open%20Issues.htm");`

Got this:
`Exception message: The system cannot find the file specified`

I tried adding this to the Web.config file and still got the same error.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: I can't get over the fact that you are using webforms :(

Comment: I can't get over the fact that they took away the designer view.
Total regression.

Comment: I'm not familiar with web forms as I haven't used them in ten years but since you are publishing this project and your error message is about a file not found, I'd first check that the publish location file path is the same. Generally you would not want to use absolute file paths in application code ... rather everything is relative to a root location for the project, or to a virtual root directory (aka webroot).

Comment: Thanks TopSail, I've already gone over this, but it appears to be an issue with impersonation. I tried Windows auth, but this presents issues with either asking for credentials repeatedly versus a change in a browser setting in IE (which is disabled in our enterprise so not feasible)

Comment: Hey @topsail - you use ASP.NET Core, does this have a graphical UI designer? Thought I'd ask quickly before going down that rabbit hole.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge WebForms with web designers are still supported in .Net Core. I would recommend waiting about four weeks for .Net 8 to be released for the best possible feature support. For example, see: [design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/)

Comment: Ah correction, web forms is still Net Framework but is supported (more or less) by Visual Studio 2022 for ongoing development work. There have been difficulties porting webforms to .Net Core.  [vs2022-web-forms-tip.aspx](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/05/16/vs2022-web-forms-tip.aspx) Note that I fully agree with the advice that if you are looking for a "replacement" for webforms, Blazor is really great for rapid application development and is generally quite easy to work with - but still not really drag and drop.

Comment: In most cases,  security risks and limitations to shell out, and start 100% a whole new separate process exists. I doubt this is your goal anyway, since process start some web page will only appear on server screen. See my post below for this explain. I much suspect if you achieve elevated rights for the IIS user to run command line process on server, you not achieve your desired goal, since all that going to do is allow you to launch PDF, or word, or Excel or in this case some .html file from the command line which appears on server, and has zero to do with IIS sending web pages to client!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have this:

```
Process.Start("file:///F:/Dashboard%20Files/Open%20Issues.htm");
```

You can't use the above. You can start a process, but not one that has ANY UI output. The above is in effect a command line process, and would start a new program on ***your*** computer.

In your case, this works, since your development computer IS ALSO the web server computer.

The above is not really much different then executing this code:

Markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test message"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"                
            />
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

And the code stub:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

The result is now this:

[image]

This "seems" like the above works, but that message box is appearing on the web server computer, which also happens to be the SAME computer running the both the web server, the browser, and your code behind. So the message box is showing, but NOT though the browser.

If you publish the above to a web server, then the end result would be this:

[image]

So, your message box will show, but of course will show on the web server!

And the same issue exists with you starting a whole new separate process with process.start.

process.start will launch Excel, word, or whatever, but will launch that program on the server, and thus of course the output of that process will appear on the web server sitting in some server room.

I'll try later today to post some additional possible solutions, but the above at least explains why attempting to shell out, or start a new process on a computer running a web server will not work, since starting such a process means a separate windows program, and one that any output will be sent to the server's screen, and not sent through the server part running the web browser. Keep in mind that a web server is just a computer box. If I launch Excel, that does not THEN mean that launching word means the Excel screen see's the output from Word. The same concept applies here with the web server. The web server can dish out pages to a end user, but running a PDF viewer, or some other command line prompt on that web server does not then send that output to the web server, and eventually down to client computers that the IIS web server is sending out web pages to.

Thus, you of course can't use process.start to run software on my computer, since if you could run software on my desktop computer when I visit your web site, then of course no one would visit your site due to security reasons, and worse yet, no one would use the internet due to security risks.

Comment: No security concerns here, these are just links to .htm documents on a local share. They open in another tab within the same Edge browser. This works flawlessly on F5, but not on publish. I am basically just trying to use an Active Directory security group to authenticate the current user because they are member.

Comment: but they are opening on your computer - not through IIS web services. As I stated, for this to work, then your customers will have to gain access to the server room, and go view the copy of the web browser launched on the server - users via client side can no more see a copy of Excel, word, or some html file launched by a process start, which as I pointed out has ZERO do do with rendering web pages via IIS. Process start is the same as if you executed a command line program on that server - such output does not by magic go out via IIS web server but is much the same as launching a console app

Comment: And no, this is not about secuirty issues. I only pointed that issue out, since it not possbile to do as you ask, but if  you could do that, then the internet would be so high risk that no one would ever use the internet. So, no, this is not about a security risk, since what you asking to do (process.start) is not possbile, since process.start can ONLY start a process on the computer that executed process.start, not on some target/click computer that is connected to the web server. Process.start has ZERO to do with the IIS and the web server, and is ONLY a command line process system.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is no way to capture credentials and use those to access a resource. What a PITA. Maybe I'll just build a desktop application. Web development sucks.

Comment: More accurately, maybe WebForms suck.

Comment: Starting a command line "process" on a separate thread and one that has ZERO to do with a web server is a vast different issue here.  If you remote into my computer (or the web server) and start a new new process, you will not see the output of word or excel or some html file on YOUR computer - the output and software is running on the server computer. This is not a issue about webforms vs ANY OTHER web based technology. This only requires a basic grasp of how computers work on your part.  However, you can load + stream out that html file if you wish - I'll post some code in a bit.

Comment: Define what you mean by "access" or "use" a resource? Launching software and threads vs running a web server are 2 MASSIVE different issues.  Because you shop on amazon.com, that does not THEN mean you can use files or resources on their server, or use their database, or launch word, or Excel or launch a html file. If you want code behind on that web site to fetch a file, and then send that file to the client computer, then fine, you can. At least take time to grasp how computers and software works here. Web server can dish out files, but running them is different concpet.

Comment: Some of these files are PDF, so it complicates things a bit. I'm already digging into the ASP.NET Core as suggested earlier. I think learning something anew may be a better solution than trying to make something work that was never designed to work.

Comment: And trust me, I understand how computers work, and my usual gig is building algorithms but on occasion I say "yes" to projects without first understanding if it can even be done. It sounds like using web forms for this solution isn't going to work. I've been working with ChatGPT (because at least I was getting some solutions to try) but none of those solutions worked. I hate writing UIs, dearly, but if I can spin up some basic ugly thing just to get it done then I will be happy with that. I've got tons of other things that I need to be doing and I would like to stop wasting so much time on ths

Comment: This is not a question of webforms, it is a grasp of how web based architecture in general works. A  web server can't run, or launch files or software on MY computer. If that was possbile, then when you visit my site with cute cat pictures, then I could run software on your computer and grab your files called banking, or password files or mess with anything else on your computer. However, supplying files from web site is different  concept then a web site being able to RUN software on YOUR computer on demand. As noted, if this was possible then no one would risk using web browsers.

Comment: That makes total sense, but again, sounds like this isn't possible - even in ASP.NET Core. I've never tried to do anything like this before, which is why I am hitting so many hurdles. I think a desktop app is the way to go, based on the requirements.

I had assumed this was possible because the previous dev wrote this whole thing in HTML and it worked, it just worked - and it was hosted on a server- just like how I am trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this is not possible, unless it is run as local host. Websites cannot interact with local files, and for good reason. Credit to  @Albert D. Kallal and @topsail for explaining this.